# Not able to pass parameter stored in memory by copy rows to result step to the SQL step condition

Tags: kettle, pdi

I have  a scenario as per the two image
First pic :[image]It is the main job and it is having 1 transformationa and a job, where in the transformation, i am selecting filename and storing into copy rows to result.

Now the job is going to execute in a loop for individual files based on the filename stored in the first transformation.In the job it will first delete the records of the target table based on event_id||file_prefix= distinct event_id||file_prefix in source, and then going to insert those records from source in the next transformation.

Second Pic:[image]
My problem is i am not able to pass the filename parameter stored in the copy rows to result step to the delete SQL query(As shown in image two).Need help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are invoking this job in a parent job, you do need to send those variables as parameters from the `Executing a job...` step details, `Parameters` tab.

For instance, the following screenshot is taken from a Job execution step in a parent Job that executes a sub Job:

[image: Job step details, Parameters tab]

I hope this helps.